# Access apex variables from non visualforce markup

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I want to execute some javascript in a Visualforce page:

```
 function newWasteAssessment(){
           var siteid = '{!siteID}';
           console.log('new waste assess: '+siteid);
           if(sforce.one){
               console.log('it works;2');
               sforce.one.createRecord('Waste_Assessment__c',null,{'Site__c':siteid});
           }
       }

        function showpopup(){
            console.log('SHOWPOPUP');
            var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
            if(popup)
                console.log("got POPUP!");
        }
```

I can't use `document.getElementById("popup");` to get an `apex:outputPanel`

so I changed this:

```
<apex:outputpanel id="popup" style="diplay: none; background-color: #DBFAFB; border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;left: 30%;padding: 10px;position: absolute;z-index: 9999;width: 500px;top:1200px;">
    <apex:form >
        <!--<apex:selectRadio value="{!newWARecordType}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!LAWARecordTypes}"/>
        </apex:selectRadio> -->
        <apex:commandbutton type="button">Select 4</button>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

to this:

```
 <!-- Waste Assessment record type selection pop up -->
<div id="popup" style="diplay: none; background-color: #DBFAFB; border-style: solid;border-width: 2px;left: 30%;padding: 10px;position: absolute;z-index: 9999;width: 500px;top:1200px;">
    <form >
        <!--<apex:selectRadio value="{!newWARecordType}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!LAWARecordTypes}"/>
        </apex:selectRadio> -->
        <button type="button">Select 4</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

but I still want to use some apex variables in my radio button group. How can I do this ? Right now if I use the apex select radio inside the plain form elemtn  I get the **( under ) must be between tags** error.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098LEIAY